# Scale numbers to be <= 255?

Tags: java, language-agnostic, math, distribution

I have cells for whom the numeric value can be anything between 0 and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. I would like to color code these cells correspondingly.

If the value = 0, then r = 0. If the value is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, then r = 255. But what about the values in between?

I'm thinking I need a function whose limit as x => `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is 255. What is this function? Or is there a better way to do this?

I could just do `(value / (Integer.MAX_VALUE / 255))` but that will cause many low values to be zero. So perhaps I should do it with a log function.

Most of my values will be in the range [0, 10,000]. So I want to highlight the differences there.

Comment: Not sure why the vote to close.  It seems like a real (and good) question to me.

Comment: How can this be tagged java **and** language-agnostic?

Comment: I think you can tag it as both because there may be a general solution (better) and a java-specific one (best)

Comment: it's language agnostic, because there is a general solution, but the language I happen to be working in is Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured a log fit would be good for this, but looking at the results, I'm not so sure.

However, [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=regression) is great for [experimenting with this sort of thing](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log+fit+%7B1.0%2C0.0%7D%2C+%7B10000%2C+191.25%7D%2C+%7B2147483649%2C+256.0%7D):

I started with that, and ended up with:

```
r(x) = floor(((11.5553 * log(14.4266 * (x + 1.0))) - 30.8419) / 0.9687)
```

Interestingly, it turns out that this gives nearly identical results to Artelius's answer of:

```
r(x) = floor(255 * log(x + 1) / log(2^31 + 1)
```

IMHO, you'd be best served with a split function for 0-10000 and 10000-2^31.

Comment: Following my algebraic simplification below, I think this might serve well for you: `r(x) = floor((256./31) * log(x)/log(2))`

Comment: Yup, that's certainly simpler, though it still suffers from the issue of a bad fit compared to the values desired.

Answer (score 16):

The "fairest" linear scaling is actually done like this:

```
floor(256 * value / (Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1))
```

Note that this is just pseudocode and assumes floating-point calculations.

If we assume that Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 is 2^31, and that / will give us integer division, then it simplifies to

```
value / 8388608
```

**Why other answers are wrong**

Some answers (as well as the question itself) suggsted a variation of `(255 * value / Integer.MAX_VALUE)`. Presumably this has to be converted to an integer, either using `round()` or `floor()`.

If using `floor()`, the only `value` that produces 255 is Integer.MAX_VALUE itself. This distribution is uneven.

If using `round()`, 0 and 255 will each get hit half as many times as 1-254. Also uneven.

Using the scaling method I mention above, no such problem occurs.

**Non-linear methods**

If you want to use logs, try this:

```
255 * log(value + 1) / log(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1)
```

You could also just take the square root of the value (this wouldn't go all the way to 255, but you could scale it up if you wanted to).

Comment: this works better when it's `log(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` instead of `log(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1)`. Otherwise, every result is 0 because `log(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` is `NaN`.

Comment: Maybe the critics can now see how it is language agnostic, even though the coder is working in THE ONE TRUE LANGUAGE

Comment: @Rosarch: Good point. I might have tested my code before posting, but why would I break my vow never to use Java over something so trivial? ;) Still, as a C programmer, I should have known better...

Comment: A statement that Java could ever be in any way construed to be THE ONE TRUE LANGUAGE has GOT to be intentional flame-bait.  How did that get up-voted?

Answer (score 3):

For a linear mapping of the range 0-2^32 to 0-255, just take the high-order byte.  Here is how that would look using binary `&` and bit-shifting:

```
r = value & 0xff000000 >> 24
```

Using mod 256 will certainly return a value 0-255, but you wont be able to draw any grouping sense from the results - 1, 257, 513, 1025 will all map to the scaled value 1, even though they are far from each other.

If you want to be more discriminating among low values, and merge many more large values together, then a log expression will work:

```
r = log(value)/log(pow(2,32))*256
```

**EDIT**: Yikes, my high school algebra teacher Mrs. Buckenmeyer would faint!  `log(pow(2,32))` is the same as `32*log(2)`, and *much* cheaper to evaluate.  And now we can also factor this better, since 256/32 is a nice even 8:

```
r = 8 * log(value)/log(2)
```

`log(value)/log(2)` is actually `log-base-2 of value`, which log does for us very neatly:

```
r = 8 * log(value,2)
```

There, Mrs. Buckenmeyer - your efforts weren't entirely wasted!

Comment: Ooops, sorry, I slipped into Python there.  java.math.log does not take a second arg, so you are stuck with log(value)/log(2).

Answer (score 2):

In general (since it's not clear to me if this is a Java or Language-Agnostic question) you would divide the value you have *by* `Integer.MAX_VALUE`,  multiply by `255` and convert to an integer.

Comment: The only way to do that is to cast to a double at one point, it is more efficient to do it the other way around.

Comment: @Erich, But then you chance overflow.

Comment: You won't overflow if you divide first!

Comment: That's what I did. What did you mean by 'do it the other way around'?

Answer (score 2):

This works!  `r= value /8421504;`

8421504 is actually the 'magic' number, which equals MAX_VALUE/255.  Thus, MAX_VALUE/8421504 = 255 (and some change, but small enough integer math will get rid of it.

if you want one that doesn't have magic numbers in it, this should work (and of equal performance, since any good compiler will replace it with the actual value:

`r= value/ (Integer.MAX_VALUE/255);`

The nice part is, this will not require any floating-point values.

Comment: How so?  The values from 0-Int.Max will be distributed evenly through 0-255, won't they?

Answer (score 1):

The value you're looking for is: r = 255 * (value / Integer.MAX_VALUE).  So you'd have to turn this into a double, then cast back to an int.

Comment: Ugh, you're right, I typed that too fast.  You could have specified the correction, but I took your subtle clue and ran with it.

Comment: @Artelius: Yes you can.  Click on the down-vote again (not on the up-vote arrow)

Comment: I have edited the post, you should now be able to reverse your vote.

Comment: LOL that is OK, that is what I get for clicking Add Comment without reading what I typed.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you want brighter and brighter, that luminosity is not linear so a straight mapping from value to color will not give a good result.

The Color class has a method to make a brighter color.  Have a look at that.

Answer (score 1):

The linear implementation is discussed in most of these answers, and Artelius' answer seems to be the best.  But the best formula would depend on what you are trying to achieve and the distribution of your values.  Without knowing that it is difficult to give an ideal answer.

But just to illustrate, any of these might be the best for you:

- Linear distribution, each mapping onto a range which is 1/266th of the overall range.
- Logarithmic distribution (skewed towards low values) which will highlight the differences in the lower magnitudes and diminish differences in the higher magnitudes
- Reverse logarithmic distribution (skewed towards high values) which will highlight differences in the higher magnitudes and diminish differences in the lower magnitudes.
- Normal distribution of incidence of colours, where each colour appears the same number of times as every other colour.

Again, you need to determine what you are trying to achieve & what the data will be used for.  If you have been tasked to build this then I would strongly recommend you get this clarified to ensure that it is as useful as possible - and to avoid having to redevelop it later on.

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself the question, "What value should map to 128?"
If the answer is about a billion (I doubt that it is) then use linear.
If the answer is in the range of 10-100 thousand, then consider square root or log.

Another answer suggested this (I can't comment or vote yet). I agree.

r = log(value)/log(pow(2,32))*256

Answer (score 1):

Here are a bunch of algorithms for scaling, normalizing, ranking, etc. numbers by using Extension Methods in C#, although you can adapt them to other languages:

http://www.redowlconsulting.com/Blog/post/2011/07/28/StatisticalTricksForLists.aspx

There are explanations and graphics that explain when you might want to use one method or another.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer really depends on the behavior you want.

If you want each cell just to generally have a color different than the neighbor, go with what **akf** said in the second paragraph and use a modulo (x % 256).

If you want the color to have some bearing on the actual value (like "blue means smaller values" all the way to "red means huge values"), you would have to post something about your expected distribution of values.  Since you worry about many low values being zero I might guess that you have lots of them, but that would only be a guess.

In this second scenario, you really want to distribute your likely responses into 256 "percentiles" and assign a color to each one (where an equal number of likely responses fall into each percentile).

Answer (score 0):

If you are complaining that the low numbers are becoming zero, then you might want to normalize the values to 255 rather than the entire range of the values.

The formula would become:

currentValue / (max value of the set)

Answer (score -1):

> I could just do (value / (Integer.MAX_VALUE / 255)) but that will cause many low values to be zero.

One approach you could take is to use the modulo operator (`r = value%256;`).  <strike>Although this wouldn't ensure that `Integer.MAX_VALUE` turns out as 255,</strike> it would guarantee a number between 0 and 255.  It would also allow for low numbers to be distributed across the 0-255 range.

EDIT:

Funnily, as I test this, `Integer.MAX_VALUE % 256` does result in `255`  (I had originally mistakenly tested against `%255`, which yielded the wrong results).  This seems like a pretty straight forward solution.

Comment: It's not explicitly stated, but it seems implicit in the question that the colours should group similar values - i.e. if two cells share a colour then their value will be roughly equivalent.  In your answer the colour has not relation to the magnitude of the value.

Comment: Kirk, I agree that the idea of distribution into buckets of similar values was *an* idea. It also appears that the OP was open to other solutions. It does seem, however, that the most of the answerers have taken the grouping of similar values as the only solution.